# Angular - ng-repeat not updating on update of nested array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I am rendering data  using ng-repeat through GET request, which retrieves an array.

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="candidateCtrl" >
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>NO</th>
                <th>NAMA</th>
                <th>NIP</th>
                <th>INSTANSI</th>
                <th><span ng-show="animateCandidateAdmin" class="ion-load-a"></span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="candidate in candidatesAdmin">
            <tr class="well whel">
                <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                <td>{{candidate.candidate_name}}</td>
                <td>{{candidate.candidate_nip}}</td>
                <td>{{candidate.candidate_institusi}}</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" ng-show="candidate.m_assesment_assesment_id == NULL" ng-click="addCandidate3(candidate.candidate_id)">
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div><!-- OFF-MAINBAR -->
  <div ng-repeat="item in percentage_penilaian" >
       <div id="candidate_{{item.m_assesment_assesment_id}}" >
           <div class="panel-body">
               <div class="table-responsive">
                   <table class="table table-striped">
                      <thead>
                          <tr>
                              <th>NO</th>
                              <th>NAMA</th>
                              <th>NIP</th>
                              <th>INSTANSI</th>
                              <th>BOBOT</th>
                              <th>SKOR</th>
                              <th>NILAI</th>
                              <th><span ng-show="animateCandidateManagerial" class="ion-load-a"></span>
                              </th>
                           </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody>
                           <tr ng-repeat="candidate in candidates[item.m_assesment_assesment_id]" class="well whel">
                               <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                               <td>{{candidate.candidate_name}}</td>
                               <td>{{candidate.candidate_nip}}</td>
                               <td>{{candidate.candidate_institusi}}</td>
                               <td>{{candidate.percentage}}%</td>
                               <td ng-show="candidate.skor != NULL">                                                                             
                                    <button  ng-click="$eval(arrAddCandidate[percentage_penilaian[$parent.$index+1].m_assesment_assesment_id])(candidate.candidate_id)"><i class="ion-arrow-right-a"></i> Mengikuti {{percentage_penilaian[$parent.$index+1].assesment_name}}</button>
                               </td>
                             </tr>
                           </tbody>
                       </table>
                   </div><!-- OFF-MAINBAR -->
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

JS

```
    <script>
    var SITEURL = "<?php echo site_url() ?>";
    var selectionApp = angular.module("selectionApp", ["isteven-multi-select"]);

    selectionApp.controller('candidateCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.candidates = [];
        $scope.arrAddCandidate = [];

        $scope.getPercentagePenilaian = function () {
            var url = SITEURL + 'xxx/xxx/' + 14;
            $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
                $scope.percentage_penilaian = response.data;
                for(var i in response.data){ 
                     $scope.arrAddCandidate[response.data[i].m_assesment_assesment_id] = "addCandidate"+response.data[i].m_assesment_assesment_id;                                                                                                                                                                              

                }
            })

        };

        $scope.getCandidateAdmin = function () {
           var url = SITEURL + 'api/get_candidate_admin/' + 14;
           $http.get(url).then(function (response) {                                                                                  
             $scope.candidatesAdmin = response.data;
           })

        };                                                                          

        $scope.get_3 = function () {
            var url = SITEURL + 'xxx/xxx/3__14';
            $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.candidates[3] = response.data;
                    // $scope.candidates.push(response.data);
                });
            })

        };
        $scope.addCandidate3 = function (id) {
            $scope.animateCandidateAdmin = true;
            var postData = $.param({
                                candidate_id: id,
                                assesment_id: 3                                                                                                });
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: SITEURL + "xx/xxx/xxxxx",
                data: postData,
                success: function (response) {
                    if(response=='sukses'){
                        $scope.animateCandidateAdmin = false;
                        $scope.getCandidateAdmin();
                        $scope.get_3();
                    }
                }
            });

        };

        $scope.get_5 = function () {
            var url = SITEURL + 'xx/xxx/5__14';
            $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
                $scope.$applyAsync(function () {
                    $scope.candidates[5] = response.data;
                    // $scope.candidates.push(response.data);
                });
            })

        };
        $scope.addCandidate5 = function (id) {
            $scope.animateCandidateAdmin = true;
            var postData = $.param({
                                candidate_id: id,
                                assesment_id: 5                                                                                                });
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: SITEURL + "xx/xxx/xxxxx",
                data: postData,
                success: function (response) {
                    if(response=='sukses'){
                        $scope.animateCandidateAdmin = false;
                        $scope.getCandidateAdmin();
                        $scope.get_5();
                    }
                }
            });

        };
        angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            $scope.getPercentagePenilaian();
            $scope.get_3;
            $scope.get_5;
        });
    });                
</script>
```

Response from $scope.getCandidateAdmin

```
[{"candidate_id":"24","candidate_name":"contoh","candidate_nip":"12345","candidate_institusi":"Institusi A","selection_selection_id":"14"}]
```

Response $scope.getPercentagePenilaian

```
[{"id":"14","m_assesment_assesment_id":"3","percentage":"50"},
{"id":"15","m_assesment_assesment_id":"5","percentage":"10"}]
```

Response from $scope.get_3

```
[{"id":"43","selection_selection_id":"14","m_assesment_assesment_id":"3"
,"candidate_id":"24","m_candidate_id" :"1","candidate_name":"contoh","candidate_nip":"12345","candidate_institusi":"Institusi A","competency_skor":null}]
```

After I adding candidate, I believe that the $scope.candidates array is updated correctly, however the table in my view does not change. I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: i've tried, it doesn't work

Comment: Can you provide some sample data for from the your AJAX request since you do not provide a URL?

Comment: just edited the question

Answer (score 0):

### Potential Issue

I think 'm_assesment_assesment_id' is stored as a String and not a Integer, which is the root of your problem.

```
[
  { "id":"14",
    "m_assesment_assesment_id":"3",  // Note: the numbers are wrapped in quotes
    "percentage":"50"
  },
  { "id":"15",
    "m_assesment_assesment_id":"5", // JSON parsers will interpret these as Strings, NOT numbers
    "percentage":"10"}
]
```

### Background to Understanding Problem

Since the `ng-repeat` is using the `item.m_assesment_assesment_id` property, Angular resolves these as Strings. When this String is passed into the Array, the Array is interpreted as a JavaScript Object and not an array. For example:

```
// Both the following evaluate to the same thing
// Using dot accessor
item.m_assesment_assesment_id
// Using square brackets to access data through Object Notation
item["m_assesment_assesment_id"]
```

This is why JavaScript interprets your Array as an Object, using `item.m_assesment_assesment_id` as a **key** and not and **index**.

```
<!-- item.m_assesment_assesment_id will evaluate as a String as the JSON data specifies the String format, triggering Object evaluation, not Array evaluation -->
<tr ng-repeat="candidate in candidates[item.m_assesment_assesment_id]" class="well whel">
```

Here is some good overview of Array Evaluation:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

> Associative Arrays Many programming languages support arrays with
>   named indexes.
>
> Arrays with named indexes are called associative arrays (or hashes).
>
> JavaScript does not support arrays with named indexes.
>
> In JavaScript, arrays always use numbered indexes.

### Solutions

There are a couple of solutions. If you have access to manipulating the JSON formatting, I would recommend correcting the problem there:

```
{  
   "id":"14",
   "m_assesment_assesment_id": 3,  // No quote == Integer
   "percentage":"50"
}
```

But this would require you to have access to the server code constructing the response and there may be architectural reasons for using a string.

Alternatively, you could change your ng-repeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="candidate in candidates[parseInt(item.m_assesment_assesment_id)]" class="well whel">
```

However there is a performance loss as this requires more processing during Angular's `$digest()` event. This will not be significant for small datasets, but it is worth noting.

If you don't have access to changing the JSON formatting on the server and you don't want to put extra load on the `$digest` event, your control could process the response data from the AJAX calls. This is often the approach recommended by Angular documentation.

```
angular.module("selectionApp", ["isteven-multi-select"])
  .controller('candidateCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.candidates = [];
        $scope.arrAddCandidate = [];

        $scope.getPercentagePenilaian = function () {
            var url = SITEURL + 'xxx/xxx/' + 14;
            $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
                // USE OUR CONVENIENCE METHOD HERE TO CONVERT STRINGS TO INTEGERS
                $scope.percentage_penilaian = processPercentagePenilaian(response.data);
                for(var i in response.data){ 
                    $scope.arrAddCandidate[response.data[i].m_assesment_assesment_id] = "addCandidate"+response.data[i].m_assesment_assesment_id;                                                                                                                                                                              

            }
        })

    };

   // *** MORE of your code exists between these functions

   // ALSO YOU HAVE TO CALL THIS IN THE CALLBACK OF THE APPROPRIATE AJAX CALLBACK
   var processPercentagePenilaian = function(items) {
      // Loop through the Items
      angular.forEach(items, function(item, key) {
         // For Every Item, convert the m_assesment_assesment_id to an Integer
         item.m_assesment_assesment_id = parseInt(item.m_assesment_assesment_id);
      });

// End Controller
});
```

Comment: still doesnt update the table.
It seems this button
`<button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" ng-show="candidate.m_assesment_assesment_id == NULL" ng-click="addCandidate3(candidate.candidate_id)">` 
but if I add next assesment from this
`<button  ng-click="$eval(arrAddCandidate[percentage_penilaian[$parent.$index+1].m_assesment_assesment_id])(candidate.candidate_id)"><i class="ion-arrow-right-a"></i> Mengikuti {{percentage_penilaian[$parent.$index+1].assesment_name}}</button>` it works updating next repeat from `ng-repeat="item in percentage_penilaian"`

Comment: So the issue happens after you click the a button, which updates the a Rest API? That wasn't clear from your original post. So, after you update the data in the ng-repeat isn't updating? In this case, you either have to update the array as you Post to the api OR you have to re-run the Get Request to update the view with the new data OR update the array at the correct index using .then(function(response) { // update array Post Response to update the correct index in the Array HERE }). Angular uses shallow references and cannot monitor changes to objects within Arrays.